# Dynamodb unexpected key KeyConditionExpression in Query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to query a table called "user_path_summary" for a value that is equal to my hashkey, "username" and also equal to my global secondary index hashkey, "full_path".  I am hoping to get back one attribute, "articles_read".  The parameters that I am using are:

```
var params = {
        "TableName": "user_path_summary",
        "IndexName": "full_path_index",
        "KeyConditionExpression": "full_path = :v_full_path AND username = v:username",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":v_username": {"S" : username},
            ":v_full_path": {"S": full_path}
        },
        "ProjectionExpression": "articles_read",
        "ScanIndexForward": false
    };
```

I get the following error.

```
{ [MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors:
* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'KeyConditions' in params
* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params]
  message: 'There were 2 validation errors:\n* MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key \'KeyConditions\' in params\n* UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key \'KeyConditionExpression\' found in params',
  code: 'MultipleValidationErrors',
  errors: 
   [ { [MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'KeyConditions' in params]
       message: 'Missing required key \'KeyConditions\' in params',
       code: 'MissingRequiredParameter',
       time: Sat Aug 01 2015 14:54:52 GMT-0400 (EDT) },
     { [UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'KeyConditionExpression' found in params]
       message: 'Unexpected key \'KeyConditionExpression\' found in params',
       code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
       time: Sat Aug 01 2015 14:54:52 GMT-0400 (EDT) } ],
  time: Sat Aug 01 2015 14:54:52 GMT-0400 (EDT) }
```

I am confused because the error pertains to the missing parameter "KeyConditions", which is identified as a legacy parameter in the [query API Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#API_Query_RequestSyntax), and also to the unexpected parameter "KeyConditionExpression" which the api reference says to use instead of "KeyConditions".

Is there a setting somewhere that I am missing?  Is my syntax messed up somewhere.  Please let me know, I am clearly missing something.

Comment: I think its also important to note that I am running my requests through nodejs using the aws-sdk that I downloaded through npm.  (npm install aws-sdk)

Comment: You have `v:username` in your **KeyConditionExpression**  and `:v_full_path` in your **ExpressionAttributeValues**. I would think you would get a different validation error for not having the correct amount of substitutions. Is there a typo?

Comment: Is the SDK that you are using the latest version of the DynamoDB API?  The "KeyConditionExpression" parameter replaced the "KeyConditions" a while back, but if you are using a very old version of the SDK that *may* explain this error.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It turns out that I had an outdated aws-sdk.